# XSL Transform of XML into drop-down html menu

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have the following XML output:

```
<payload>
<MenuItems>
<id>1</id>
<menuTitle>Members</menuTitle>
<description/>
<menuURL>members</menuURL>
<menuTarget/>
<parentID>0</parentID>
</MenuItems>
<MenuItems>
<id>2</id>
<menuTitle>Tiers</menuTitle>
<description/>
<menuURL>tiers</menuURL>
<menuTarget/>
<parentID>1</parentID>
</MenuItems>
</payload>
```

And I need to transform it (using XSLT) into an html menu, as follows:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="menuURL">menuTitle</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="menuURL" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menuTitle <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="menuURL">menuTitle</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

In other words, the top-level menu items (where parentID = 0) should show in the main menu.

The submenu items (where parentID = the id of the parent menu item, should show in the drop-down menu for that parent.

This seems like it should be an easy transform using XSL, but for some reason I can't seem to get it to work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the current XSL I've been working with.  I feel like it's very close (the main menu items are pulling correctly), but I can't quite get the submenus to pull.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" standalone="no" indent="yes"/> 


<xsl:template match="pkgInfo">
      <xsl:for-each select="payload">
      </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="payload">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="MenuItems[parentID=0]"/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="MenuItems">
            <li><a href="{menuURL}"><xsl:value-of select="menuTitle"/></a></li>
            <xsl:param name="currentParent" select="id" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="MenuItems[parentID=$currentParent]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MenuItems">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="{menuURL}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">   
<xsl:value-of select="menuTitle"/> <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="menuURL"><xsl:value-of select="menuTitle"/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel like I'm really close but I can't quite figure out how to get the submenus to pull correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="payload">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MenuItems">
        <xsl:variable name="currentParent" select="id" />
        <xsl:if test="parentID='0'">
            <li class="active"><a href="{menuURL}"><xsl:value-of select="menuTitle"/></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="{menuURL}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><xsl:value-of select="menuTitle"/> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::MenuItems[parentID=$currentParent]" mode="nest"/>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MenuItems[parentID != '0']" mode="nest">
        <li><a href="{menuURL}"><xsl:value-of select="menuTitle"/></a></li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input XML, it produces:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="members">Members</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="members" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Members<b class="caret"
            ></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="tiers">Tiers</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```